# Can't apply meshgrid directly to create Surfaceplot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, array-broadcasting

Consider the following example:

```
from numpy import array, exp, linspace, meshgrid
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
y = array([10, 5.49, 0.89, -0.14, -1.07, 0.84])
a1, a2 = 1, 4

def model(x, a1, a2):
    return a1 * exp(-a2 * x)

def residuen(x, y, a1, a2):
    return modell(x, a1, a2) - y

def S(x, y, a1, a2): 
    return 0.5 * sum(residuen(x, y, a1, a2) ** 2)
```

The input values `x` and `y` are fixed. I want to compute values of the function `S` for different values of `a1`, `a2` and display the result as a 3D - surface plot. In a [matplotlib tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html), I found an example that uses the `meshgrid` function. I tried to apply this function for my problem:

```
a1 = linspace(-100, 100, 1000)
a2 = linspace(-100, 100, 1000)
A1, A2 = meshgrid(a1, a2)
Z = S(x, y, A1, A2)
```

When I run this code, I get the error

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1000,1000) (6,)
```

It is clear why the above code does not work, but I do not know how fix/redefine the function `S` so that I can apply the `meshgrid` function to get the desired values Z for the surface plot. Does someone have an idea how fix this problem?

Comment: It's extremely unclear what you want to do. Please figure out how you plan on combining all the arrays. Write a for loop to make the array you want, and we can help you vectorize it.

Comment: a1 and a2 represents the position of a point and S(a1, a2) is "its value / height".  So for each pair (a1, a2) i get one value S(a1, a2). All i want to do know is to compute S for different values of a1, a2 and create surface plot. That part should be clear or not? Surface plots are normally create it with numpy's meshgrid function, which i cant use in my case directly as explained above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your error indicates, your issue really has nothing to do with matplotlib. You are attempting to compute the residual between your model and your 6 data points at each of 1e6 locations. Since the residual is a sum, you can imagine having a 1000x1000x6 array at some point and summing it across the last dimension. You can also make a 6x1000x1000 array and sum across the first dimension, but I will show the former case.

The technique you want to use is called [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html). It means lining up the shapes starting with the last dimensions, and filling out unit dimensions to match. The simplest change to make to introduce broadcasting is in `model`:

```
a1[..., None] * exp(-a2[..., None] * x)
```

The ellipsis (`...`) in `[..., None]` means "take all the existing dimensions". It is a shorthand for doing `[:, :]` in this case, but as many times as necessary for the particular array. The `None` is equivalent to [`np.newaxis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/constants.html#numpy.newaxis), and means "add a unit dimension". To in total, the indexing expression is an idiomatic way to append a dimension to your shape. Another way would be to do something like `a1.reshape(a1.shape + (1,))`.

Now you have the following operations:

1. Multiply shape `(1000, 1000, 1)` (expanded `a2`) by shape `(6,)` (`x`) -> Result shape: `(1000, 1000, 6)`. The last dimension of `a2` is **broadcasted**. `x` is given two implicit leading dimensions of size `1`, which are also **broadcasted**.

   This is where your error occurred. You can't multiply arrays of shape `(1000, 1000)` and `(6,)` in a meaningful way element-wise, but you can with the new unit dimension(s).
2. Exponent of shape `(1000, 1000, 6)` array retains shape.
3. Multiply result by shape `(1000, 1000, 1)` (expanded `a1`). The last dimension is **broadcasted**.

Now the residual in `residuen` is perfectly fine: `modell(x, a1, a2) - y` finds the difference between a `(1000, 1000, 6)` array and a `(6,)` array. The final dimensions line up perfectly and broadcasting takes care of the rest.

The only other difference is that you have to tell [`sum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html) which axis to operate on, since your arrays are no longer flat:

```
0.5 * sum(residuen(x, y, a1, a2)**2, axis=1)
```

This is not exactly a proper RMS computation though. I would have expected to see

```
sum(residuen(x, y, a1, a2)**2, axis=-1)**0.5
```

A simpler way to find the RMS of an array is to use [`np.linalg.norm`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html):

```
np.linalg.norm(residuen(x, y, a1, a2), axis=-1)
```

**TL;DR**

Your program needs to use broadcasting:

```
x = array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
y = array([10, 5.49, 0.89, -0.14, -1.07, 0.84])
a1 = np.linspace(-100, 100, 1000)[None, :]
a2 = np.linspace(-100, 100, 1000)[:, None]

def model(x, a1, a2):
    return a1[..., None] * exp(-a2[..., None] * x)

def residuen(x, y, a1, a2):
    return model(x, a1, a2) - y

def S(x, y, a1, a2): 
    return np.linalg.norm(residuen(x, y, a1, a2), axis=-1)

Z = S(x, y, A1, A2)
```